# Hadoop installation on windows?

Tags: windows, apache, hadoop

Could any one provide me with step-by-step tutorial how to install hadoop on windows.
I read official manual, but I can't get from it where should I input scripts from manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the [instructions](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html) for setting up Hadoop on Windows. BTW. currently Hadoop on Windows is OK for development, but now for production.

HortonWorks and Microsoft are working on porting Hadoop to Azure and Windows Server. As of this writing this is in limited preview. If you are interested in this then follow this [Avkash](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/). the author has been extensively blogging.

> I read official manual, but i can't get from it where should I input scripts from manual.

What official manual are you referring to? Not clear about the second part.

Comment: Official tutorial [there](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html) When i mean that I can't understand properly what should I do with the scripts I mean scripts from Linux terminal, which mentioned in the article. Problem is there are no analog for windows.

Comment: Follow the tutorial mentioned in the above answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried this one and this stuff worked well:

http://pages.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs147a/lab/hadoop-windows/