# Installing Hadoop on windows 7 with 32 bit processor?

Tags: windows, hadoop

I have a 32 bit machine with windows 7, 
I need to install hadoop and try it out, I checked Cloudera distribution and it is for linux, VMWare images with 64 bit processor.
How do I install Hadoop on windows 7 with 32 bit processor?

Comment: Flagged this as should be on ServerFault.com. Try searching there first, and if you can't find anything, you can move this question from here to there pretty easily.

Comment: Similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034588/hadoop-instalation-on-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034588/hadoop-instalation-on-windows)

Comment: Please refer below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636366/how-to-install-big-data-hadoop-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-vm-on-windows-7-32-bit-an

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the closest thing is that you can install VMWare Player, a linux distro as a virtual machine on the top of VMWare and then the Hadoop packages on your virtual linux box. But that's slow and I wouldn't recommend it.

There's no Hadoop for windows.

Comment: Microsoft and HortonWorks are working on migrating Hadoop to Windows Server and Azure.

Comment: Hadoop version 2.2 onwards includes native support for Windows.

Comment: Yeah. Answer date: February 2012. Apache Hadoop 1.0: November 2012.

Answer (score 3):

You can install Hadoop on windows if you install cygwin see http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html 
Also Microsoft is working with Hortonworks to bring Hadoop to windows properly but for now it is only [available on Azure](https://www.hadooponazure.com/). I understands there are plans to make it available on windows in general in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Hadoop version 2.2 onwards includes native support for Windows.
>
> Do not attempt to run the installation from within Cygwin. Cygwin is
>   neither required nor supported.

Figure out more information at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

Answer (score 0):

Try [Hortonworks' Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/), it's good for learning the (very) basics.