# How to install Big Data Hadoop on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit VM on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have a Windows 7 32-bit laptop and I wanted to practice Hadoop on Ubuntu 64 bit. I tried many ways but was not able to install/run Hadoop since it requires 64 bit Ubuntu OS.  How can I install it on my Windows 32-bit laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good day,

Finally I have managed to run **Ubuntu 64 bit VM** on my **Windows 7 32 bit** and installed **Hadoop** in Ubuntu.

This thread is just for those who wants to practice hadoop on Ubuntu 64 bit in Windows 7 32 bit computer...

Please follow below steps/links i have provided, please let me know if you come across any issues on this..

1) First step **main Important**, your computer/laptop CPU should support to **64 bit architecture** and it should support to **Virtualization**. please follow below links to check these compatibility.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ==

http://www.sysprobs.com/64bit-guest-os-32bit-host-os-vmware

and also please check and Enable **Virtualization in BIOS** if your CPU is supporting. I think most of the latest CPU support this.

continue below steps only if above are supporting.

2) Download **Vmware Workstation 10** from this link [VMWare link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation/10_0)

This is not free software, you have to use Trial version or Purchase it or any other way, but you need to install it on your windows 7 32 bit computer.

3) After installing VMware workstation 10, now you need to download **Ubuntu 14 64 bit ISO** from this site [Ubuntu 64 bit ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

4) After downloading Ubuntu 64 bit ISO, Now you need to install it on VMware. I have not provided the steps how to install it on vmware but it easy and if you face any issue you can Google for this.

if you successfully install the Ubuntu 64 bit on VM then you all done :)....

5) Now its time to get into Ubuntu VM and install the **Java** and **Hadoop**... please follow the below links for these...

Installing Java on Ubuntu 14. link [Install JAVA on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Installing Hadoop on Ubuntu 14 link [Installing Hadoop on Ubuntu](http://dogdogfish.com/2014/04/26/installing-hadoop-2-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Now you all done, hopefully it will be help full for the peoples who want to practice Hadoop on Ubuntu on their Windows 7 32 bit computer/Laptop...

If you face any issues on this installation, please free to comment here will try my level best to answer and resolve the issue... :)

Thank you...

Comment: I like the way you did it :) +1